# update table using LAG function

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, lag

I have the st_12_test table.

```
CREATE TABLE public.st_12_test
(
  mmsi numeric,
  x1 double precision,
  y1 double precision,
  datetime timestamp without time zone,
  x2 double precision,
  y2 double precision,
  linetime double precision
)
```

I am trying to udapte the x2 column (which is empty) by adding the value of the previous row in the column x1. I am able to view the results by using a query like this:

```
SELECT  *, lag(x1,1) OVER (PARTITION BY mmsi) AS x2 FROM st_12_test;
```

but I am not able to update the x2 column of the table. I get this ERROR: cannot use window function in UPDATE, e.g. when I try to run something like this:

```
UPDATE st_12_test SET x2 = LAG(x1,1) OVER (PARTITION BY mmsi);
```

any idea?

Comment: `lag()` without an `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause doesn't make sense. Define "previous".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CTE which uses the LAG function. Then use the resulting  data in an Update...From. **Assuming** previous is defined based on the datetime column then:

```
with ts12cte (mmsi, datetime, prev_x) as 
   ( select mmsi, datetime
          , lag(x1) over (partition by mmsi order by mmsi, datetime) 
       from st_12_test
   ) 
update st_12_test  st  
   set x2 = cte.prev_x   
  from ts12cte  cte
 where st.mmsi = cte.mmsi
   and st.datetime = cte.datetime;
```

Since you did not provide test data it has not been tested. It does however pass syntax validation.